# Что значит термин распределенная гипермедиа система?

Tags: сеть, rest, distribution

При попытке изучить понятие REST-архитектуры, меня испугал термин распределенного приложения. Поскольку сети не изучал, то хотел бы получить понимание у знатоков, что это значит.

Что такое распределенное приложение в сети или распределенная гипермедиа система?